# What happens to my restricted stock in the eBay & PayPal spin-off?

Tags: stocks, paypal, rsu, ebay, spin-off

Currently I hold **vested** restricted stock units in eBay.  According to the media, after the spin-off, eBay shareholders will receive a PayPal stock for each eBay stock they own.

Does this applies to vested RSUs as well?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that if your RSUs are vested, they aren't really RSUs anymore: they are simply shares.

Comment: @BenMiller AFAIK I think you are correct, but I'm not 100% sure. they are Vested & sellable for couple years now.

Comment: have you received your PayPal shares after eBay & PayPal spin-off? I hold eBay vested RSU as well and now my eTrade account only has eBay shares and no PayPal shares. Not sure what happened.

Comment: Same here, only ebay shares (worth half as much) showing in my acct now.  Assume pypl will show up sometime soon.

Comment: I see PYPL stocks on etrade , but no amount (shows zero)

Comment: @Cherry mine are Vested. probably different with non Vested stocks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted out now. hopefully for all of us.

I see the same amount of stocks for both ppl & eBay.

now, wondering what to do with the eBay stocks...
probably sell in favor of dividend stocks of some sort

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it applies to vested RSU. You will receive them in your account but it usually takes a while (could be weeks).

Comment: I already see them (PYPL) but with a 0 amount & eBay stocks have been cut in their price... weeks of stress 